# How to display svg image after load?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an input file type:

```
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="openFile($event)" />
```

Method opens file:

```
openFile(event: Event) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    this.read(input);
}
```

Method reads a data:

```
private read(input) {
        const fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg'];

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            const extension = input.files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),
                isSuccess = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1;

            if (isSuccess) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                        const data = reader.result;

                        // HOW create svg image here?

                        const = svg; // create svg here from data image
                        document.getElementBy('block').appendChild(svg);
                    
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            } else {
                console.log('Wring image type');
            }
        }
    }
```

So when I load a SVG image I get content of it. How to place image in block `id="block"` based `data`?

**SVG image looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174"
     xml:space="preserve">
<ellipse fill="#C6C6C6" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
<path id="bird" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
    c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
```

As you can see image file has svg tag.

For `readAsText` I get this:

[image: �PNG]

For readAsDataURL:

[image]

Comment: That's png data you have there, not SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i think it too simple, but you can read the file as text (`reader.readAsText()`) and simply use `innerHTML` for inserting the svg. To get this to work you have to:

- change the `(change)` listener in your input to an ordinary `onchange` listener,
- take the event param for the event handler `openFile()` without a `$` and
- declare your functions as ordinary functions with `function` instead of `private`

---

**Working example:**
I saved your example svg on my PC, closed the `path` tag and added a closing `svg` tag) and uploaded it using the input.

I don't know why you have that extra function `openFile()`, but i let it like in your example. But you could just use `read(event)` and `reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);`.

```js
function openFile(event) {
  this.read(event.target);
}

function read(input) {
  const fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg'];

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    const extension = input.files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),
      isSuccess = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1;

    if (isSuccess) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      if (extension == "svg") {
        reader.onload = () => {
          document.getElementById('block').innerHTML = reader.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
      }
      else {
        // proceed the other image types
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log('Wrong image type');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" accept="image/*" onchange="openFile(event)">

<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: It does not work for me:

`Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: `const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                    const data = reader.result;
                    document.getElementById('block').innerHTML = data;
                };

                reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);`

Comment: I have tried this, no effect:

` const data = reader.result;
                    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
                    document.getElementById('block').innerHTML = blob.arrayBuffer.toString();`

Comment: Culd you paste the ```reader.result``` in a code snippet in your question? At best for both cases: ```readAsText``` and ```readAsDataURL```...

Comment: I have posted both results in question, so I want place svg to be able manage it using JS

Comment: I can not use img as svg, because I can not modify svg then using JS. I nede to inset SVG file not converting to img

Comment: I need to place svg from input file in div then to be able modify it using JS

Comment: Since your code didn't work in my test file as plain Javascript (like you tagged the question), i "translated" it to Javascript that i know and it worked with ```readAsText()``` and ```innerHTML```.

Comment: Could you share an sample I did not get you

Comment: I get this TS error usng your example:

`Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232848/discussion-between-biberman-and-megan-clerc).

Answer (score 0):

more modern code would use blob's new read methods such as arrayBuffer(), text() and stream()

```
function openFile(event) {
  this.read(event.target)
}

async function read(input) {
  const fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg']
  
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    const extension = input.files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),
    isSuccess = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1

    if (isSuccess) {
      if (extension == 'svg') {
        const svg = await input.files[0].text()
        document.getElementById('block').innerHTML = svg
      }
      else {
        // proceed the other image types
        const img = new Image()
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0])
        document.getElementById('block').append(img)
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log('Wrong image type')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could I create URL.createobjectUrlk from SVGElement?

Comment: Yes, you could but you would not be able to interact with the svg with javascript, and the mime type would have to be `image/svg+xml` you can create a new Blob by doing: `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file], { type: 'image/svg+xml' }))`

Comment: Infact, it would be safer if you did append the svg as a `<img>` instead